# How to achive custom shaped container?

Tags: flutter

[image: reference image]

I want to achieve a curved container like this. I tried with cliprrect but couldn't really achieve that shape. I found CustomPaint and looked into it, but not really understand how to use it or how to begin to draw that shape.

Comment: Literally same question asked here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170150/how-to-achieve-a-custom-shaped-container-in-flutter

Comment: How is it the same question? I want to paint a completely different shape than that.

Comment: We can't give you exactly same solution you want, you need to learn how to draw shapes, then you can do anything you want

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.